# Need to calculate distance (Node to Node) along the lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, line, network, distance-matrix

I have a Shapefile (polygon), I need to calculate distance (Node to Node) along the lines in map unit(meter or kilometer).

I want to do it in ArcGIS.

Comment: Please answer requests for clarification by **editing** the question. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information. Every question should always state the software environment in the question body. Please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand what is expected.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about dimensioning?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be converting your polygon to lines and then, split the lines at vertices. From here, the resulting geometry will have a shape length, otherwise you can also calculate geometry in the table of contents.

[1. Feature to line](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-line.htm)

[2. Split line at vertices](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/gp_toolref/data_management_tools/split_line_at_vertices_data_management_.htm)

Comment: i want to calculate distance between each node along the line in matrix form where the unit should be in meter or kilometer

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, can you add some screens? You should probably edit the question for better understanding as Vince suggested you.